# Display editable dropdown in DataGridView for custom class Enum property

Tags: .net, datagridview, enums, combobox

I am binding custom class to Datagridview and want to show Editable combobox for one of the Enum property.

```
Public Class Contact

    Public Enum GenderTypes
        Male
        Female
    End Enum

    Private _Firstname As String
    Private _Lastname As String
    Private _Gender As GenderTypes

    Public Property FirstName() As String
        Get
            Return Me._Firstname
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            Me._Firstname = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property LastName() As String
        Get
            Return Me._Lastname
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            Me._Lastname = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property Gender() As GenderTypes
        Get
            Return Me._Gender
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As GenderTypes)
            Me._Gender = value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```

In Form1 i am binding List(Of Contact) like following.

```
Dim mContacts As List(Of Contact) = New List(Of Contact)
dgContacts.DataSource = mContacts
```

Now,when i run the application in datagridview didn't create editable combobox for gender enum property of my custom class. I tried to create custom EnumConverter but didn't make the enum property to editable dropdown.

Please let me know how i'll get the editable combobox/dropdown in datagridview for my custom class enum property.

Answer (score 1):

In the EditingControlShowing event of your datagridview, set the drop down style of that column comobo box to DropDown. Below is the sample.

```
if (MyGridView.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex.Equals(GenderColumn.Index) && (e.Control is ComboBox))
  {
    var genderCombox = e.Control as ComboBox;
    genderCombox.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDown;
  }
```

This should make your gender combo box editable.